# SSI: Use regex to parse variable

Tags: regex, url, ssi

i've got the part of the url that i need with the following SSI command:

```
<!--#set var="uriVariable" value="$DOCUMENT_URI" -->
```

Now i should extract the first part of this string like in the below example:

```
uriVariable = "/questions/ask.html"
-- operation on the uriVariable --
parsedURI = "/questions/"
```

Comment: Try the regex `^\/[^\/]+\/`

Answer (score 0):

Issue **solved** with the following code:

```
<!--#if expr="v('DOCUMENT_URI') =~ /([a-z]{2}_[a-z0-9]{2,5})/ && $1 =~ /([a-z]{2}_[a-z0-9]{2,5})/"-->
<!--#set var="contextPath" value="$0" -->
<!--#endif -->

<!--#echo var="contextPath" -->
```